# Is there a way to intercept unspecified properties in a Vue component and pass it on to the base html tag within the component?

Tags: vue.js

The objective is to have a base html element in the Vue component:

```
<template>
<div>
<template>
.....
export default {
name: 'derivedDiv'
props: [definedProp]
}
```

when specifying I want to specify this as

```
<derived-div defined-prop="20" class="undef-prop-class" id="id-to-be-passed-to-div" key="not-def-but-to-div>"
```

then capture these props and put them to the div 
this something like **kwargs in python when deriving classes.

```
created (){
foreach (undefined property.... assign property to the base div)
```

This way I want to be able to inherit basic html properties for a vue component and have flexibility to use them later rather than defining them first.

Comment: This should happen by default anyway, except for `key` which has a special meaning in Vue. https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#inheritAttrs